# sync local dir with github repo

Tags: git, github, filesystems

If I am editing a repository and pushing to a public repository on github, is there a way for another computer to automatically keep a local copy of the most up-to-date version of that repository?

How can I keep a local folder synced with a github repository?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to run `git pull` on the local machine. I'd assume you want to do this automatically anytime something changes in the github repository. In that case, you have two options:

1) **Polling** - *Less ideal (wasteful)* - use a [Cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or write a script that simply runs `git pull` every minute/hour or whatever timeframe suits your needs. Here is an example cron job that will pull the repo every minute

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/your/repo && git pull
```

2) **Webhooks** - *More ideal but requires running a server and exposing the machine to the public internet* - Setup a webhook on github.com that will notify your server via HTTP anytime the remote repository changes and you can pull the changes upon being notified. To set up a webhook on github.com go to

`Settings -> Webhooks & Services -> Add WebHook`

Github will send an HTTP request to your machine after certain events (commits, branches, etc) occur on the remote repository and you can handle them accordingly. In your case, probably just by running `git pull` anytime new commits are added to master